# How to add audio options to a form in html (making html code through python)

Tags: html, python-2.7

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>The Moon</title>

  <link rel="icon" type = "img/gif" href = "moonanimation.gif">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans|Megrim|Tangerine" rel="stylesheet"> 

  <!-- 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> -->

</head>

<body>


  
  <div class="navigation">

    <ul>

      <li id="logo"><a href="moonpage.html"><img src="moonanimation.gif"/></a></li>

      <li><a href="frances.html">France</a></li>

      <li><a href="kpop.html">K-Pop</a></li>

      <li><a href="latino.html">Spain and Latin America</a></li>

      <li><a href="bolly.html">Bollywood</a></li>

    </ul>

  </div>


<form method="get" action="france.py">
<center>

<audio controls>
  
Amine - Senorita<source src="Amine - Senorita.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Amir - Jai cherchete<source src="Amir - Jai cherchete.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Indila - Derniere Danse<source src="Indila - Derniere Danse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Indila- Tourner Dans Le Vide<source src="Indila- Tourner Dans Le Vide.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Kendji Girac - Cool<source src="Kendji Girac - Cool.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Kendji Girac- Andalouse<source src="Kendji Girac- Andalouse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Kendji Girac- Color Gitano<source src="Kendji Girac- Color Gitano.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Kendji Girac- Conmigo<source src="Kendji Girac- Conmigo.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Khaled - Cest la vie<source src="Khaled - Cest la vie.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->KIDS UNITED- On Ecrit Sur Les Murs<source src="KIDS UNITED- On Ecrit Sur Les Murs.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Louane - Avenir<source src="Louane - Avenir.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Louane- Maman<source src="Louane- Maman.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->MAGIC SYSTEM- Magic In The Air Feat. Chawki<source src="MAGIC SYSTEM- Magic In The Air Feat. Chawki.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Nekfeu - On Verra<source src="Nekfeu - On Verra.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Noir Desir- Le Vent Nous Portera<source src="Noir Desir- Le Vent Nous Portera.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Soprano- Cosmo<source src="Soprano- Cosmo.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Soprano- Millionnaire<source src="Soprano- Millionnaire.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Stromae - Carmen<source src="Stromae - Carmen.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Stromae - ta fete<source src="Stromae - ta fete.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Stromae- Formidable<source src="Stromae- Formidable.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Stromae- Papaoutai<source src="Stromae- Papaoutai.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Stromae- Quand cest <source src="Stromae- Quand cest .mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Stromae- Tous Les Memes<source src="Stromae- Tous Les Memes.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Zaho- Tourner la page<source src="Zaho- Tourner la page.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->Zaz - Je Veux<source src="Zaz - Je Veux.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><input type="checkbox" name="addsong" value="yes"><br><!-- 

 -->

Your browser does not support the audio element. Please try a different browser or a newer version.
</audio> 

<input type="submit" name="the-button" value="sync">

</center>
</form>


</body>

</html>
```

I am creating a website using python and html. This website will feature multiple songs that users can select through a form and add to their playlist. I have to create html pages that link to a python page so that once users select different songs on my page, their choices can be saved and displayed using python.

However, I am not sure how I can do this. I created html code with form elements, but when viewed online, only 1/26 songs are shown. Also, no checkbox is shown. How do I combine audio files and form elements so that in the browser, a user may see a check box  located next to a song name and an audio tool to listen?

Also, how can I write python code to process the selections and add to a playlist? Should I write choices to a text document through python?

Thank you in advance!

This is what I have so far (I created this through python):